# How to store Arabic Characters in Database

Tags: sql

I'm having a problem in a VB.NET application, i have a form that the user fills to store data in the database, the problem is that when i enter Arabic string, it gets stored in the database as question marks: `??????`

The database field type is nvarchar, has anybody else come across this problem?

Comment: looks like you should use UTF-8 collation

Answer (score 2):

take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295829%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) seach for Database-level collations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose an Arabic collation for your varchar/char columns or use Unicode (nchar/nvarchar)

```
CREATE TABLE #test
(
col1 VARCHAR(100) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI,
col2 VARCHAR(100) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI_KS_WS,
col3 NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO #test VALUES(N'لا أتكلم العربية',N'لا أتكلم العربية',N'لا أتكلم العربية')
```